# How to fix three.js texture issue?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3dsmax

Now I develop a 3d sofa price calculator with `three.js`

Here, I loaded **3ds file** into scene.

But I have some issue like this.

This is result in case of original 3ds file
[image: Original 3DS file]

this is result in case of UVW changed in 3ds file
[image: UV changed in 3DS Max]

As can see above image, I couldn't display correct texture.
So I tried to update UVW info in 3DS Max.

But the result is below image
This is my code

```
//load textures
var textureImage;
var bumpImage;
var diffuse = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
    'texture/'+texture+'.jpg',
    function(texture){
        textureImage = texture;
    },
    null,
    function(err){
        console.log('failed')
    }
);

var bump = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
    'texture/'+texture+'-bump.jpg',
    function(texture){
        bumpImage = texture;
    },
    null,
    function(err){
        console.log('failed')
    }
);

setTimeout(() => {
    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        map : textureImage,
        bumpMap : bumpImage,
        // metalness : 0.3,
        // roughness : 0.3,
    })
    console.log(material)
    for(var i in lstElement){
        var item = lstElement[i].model;
        for(var j in item.children){
            item.children[j].material = material;
        }
    }
}, 500);
```

I don't know why I can't display correct texture.

Comment: Did you set texture.wrapS to repeat?

Comment: Try to export with the A3dsViewer and check the result of the THREE.Materials. Maybe will help..